# Javascript to gather click data?

Tags: javascript, web-analytics

Is it a good idea to use Javascript to gather click data from a website?  I have a list of categories and would like to generate stats for which category is most visited, etc.  I was thinking just saving which link the user clicks using ajax..

Comment: Sounds fine, but if all the links are internal you might as well count pageviews on the serverside!

Comment: There's no reason to do this client-side. Do it server-side, where you're not sending excessive requests across the network and potentially missing events, or use something like Google Analytics where they've done the work for you.

Comment: I use [Analog](http://www.analog.cx) extensively on our Apache access log files - works great for internal links

Comment: What would you recommend other than google analytics.  I need more visualizations and information regarding my click data.  Something like amazon has on their web pages.

Answer (score 0):

your idea is good. but why just reinvent the wheel 
Use Google Analytics, and that will do exactly what you are looking for.

For more infrmation on how to embed google analytics go here

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Google Analytics is PIWIK, which is open source. If you want more visualizations than these tools give you, you may want to consider using Google Analytics or PIWIK to sessionize your data and then export it.  With the export you could front end it with a BI Tool, or develop custom reports.